# How to display items that make up a slice of a pie chart in Kibana?

Tags: kibana, visualization, pie-chart

I am attempting to create a pie chart that will display the health status of various systems. This is what the chart currently looks like:

[image]

Each data point, in addition to the possible errors messages, has a name in its data.

Is it possible to configure the chart so the system names are shown in the pie chart? In the tooltip for each slice would be preferable, but any solution will work.

Comment: Could you show visualization details where you created this pie chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `Add` (button at the buttom of the configuration) a second visualization, which will then add another layer around your first visualization.

This is an example for `log.level` and around it `labels.url.full`:

[image]